# Powershell Proper way for Getting File Count

Tags: powershell, count

What is the correct way of getting the number of files and folders within a directory? Right now I have two ways of doing it.

First:

```
$downloadsFolder=Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\" -Recurse
Write-Output ("Total Files and Folders " + $downloadsFolder.count)
```

Second:

```
Write-Output ("Calling from Get-Child-Item " + (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\" -Recurse).Length)
```

Which is correct? Is their an advantage of doing one way over the other? Will anyone of them give an inaccurate count in another situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count` is an alias property for `Length`, so there is no difference between them.

```
PS C:\> $f = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\
PS C:\> Get-Member -InputObject $f

   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name           MemberType            Definition
----           ----------            ----------
Count          AliasProperty         Count = Length
Add            Method                int IList.Add(System.Object value)
[...]
IsSynchronized Property              bool IsSynchronized {get;}
Length         Property              int Length {get;}
LongLength     Property              long LongLength {get;}
Rank           Property              int Rank {get;}
SyncRoot       Property              System.Object SyncRoot {get;}
```

It also doesn't make a difference if you use a variable or a subexpression.

```
PS C:\> $f = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\
PS C:\> $f.Length
11
PS C:\> (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\).Length
11
```

Comment: Be aware that hidden and system files would not be picked up with this without `-Force` on `Get-ChildItem`. Also need to right permissions to begin with